# Please bring back bacon as an acceptable payment for unicoins

Tags: feature-request, unicoins, payment

I spent the past 6 to 8 weeks cooking bacon because I was hoping to add a unicorn animation to my voting buttons. I really wanted it, somehow you knew.

To my dismay, and after cooking all of this bacon and even making some waffles, the payment method was disabled as a viable option.

There may be a rainbow in this image, but it is a dark day when we cannot afford unicoins with bacon.

[image]

Comment: [I know a guy...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/227578/212780)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Worked fine for me.

You need to load the bacon in first though before selecting that option. Some older machines have a button on the side that, when pressed opens up a bacon delivery tray. Just load that up with delicious bacon and you'll be good to go.

Comment: I believe that tray is commonly referred to as the [Delicatessen Variety Dispensor](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/227495/33051) although on some older machines you may only have a Condiments Dispensor, in which case you may be out of luck. I'm hoping my Unlimited Smoked Bacon connector will arrive soon.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't have waffled. Unicorns don't like it if you waffle.

Also, did you cook real bacon, or that fake Canadian stuff? There's a very sophisticated fraud detection system in play.

Comment: Argh, was that what happened?! I think I can destroy the evidence in time.

Comment: If it was fake Canadian stuff was it real fake Canadian stuff or fake American Canadian stuff? There's a HUGE difference, actually.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to quickly get a good 500 or so unicoins before this broke!

However now I'm out of bacon! I'll quite happily do you a swap (250 unicoins for some of your bacon?).

If not, it's always a viable option to pay via twitter followers.

Comment: Or souls. Souls work well too.

Comment: Souls, blood of the first born, it's whatever the unicorns demand. @BlueIce