# How do I convert Unicoins to reputation?

Tags: discussion, reputation, unicoins

I have earned TONS of Unicoins today, but now I need to convert them for reputation on various StackExchange sites. Can someone direct me to the currency exchange that handles this?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a joke or not.. you seem a bit serious. Everyone knows that unicoins are only an April fools joke right?

Comment: @ɥʇǝS They're a what now?

Comment: @ɥʇǝS What?!?! Really? NOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO

Comment: I don't know if any of you are serious except from @ɥʇǝS (who has an awesome name)

Comment: @ɥʇǝS: Right. Tomorrow, it's all over (I'm in Italy, so there's still more than 2 hrs to April, 2nd)

Comment: `I have earned TONS of Unicorns today` - I guess your forearm now aches like hell! At least you have a metacarpal-tunnel syndrome... :D

Comment: I find interesting that you have "Psychology" in your name...

Comment: @JMCF125 ironic, isn't it? ;-)

Comment: Indeed... `:)` Glad you're not upset as some people have been by this game or such plays on words or jokes.

Comment: @Vyger you guess his forearm now aches like hell? They've been mining unicoins, not whatever you were thinking of! Dirty mind! ;)

Comment: Yes, but my mouse's button is not so soft at all. and my finger doesn't run so fast anymore... :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You tie them to a buggy, then you drive them slowly through the neighborhood.  People will talk, and trust me, that's a good thing.

Once unicorn envy sets in, those with the means will consult you on the care and feeding of their newly accquired unicorns.  Those without the means will hang around you to look like they are in with the cool crowd.

---- Edit Update, now that he refers to unicoins ----

You gather them in your living room in a huge pile.  You identify people which have esteemed your reputation weakly.  Then invite the over for some social event, like dinner.

Strip down to the minimum amount of clothing you require to feel comfortable.  Open the curtains and doors to the other living spaces.  Then wallow in your pile of unicoins at least fifteen minutes prior to the arranged social gathering.  Attempt to bathe with them.  Throw them up in the air to create a shower effect.

Upon your guests arriving, do not stop your unicoin activities, instead have someone else let your guests in.  Remember to provide enough noise to attract attention, but otherwise be oblivious to your poor unicoin bereft underlings.  After ten minutes of possible observation, end the unicoin activities, grab a bath robe or towel, and leave to the other living spaces to dress for the company.

Never mention the unicoins directly or indirectly.  If asked a question about them, look puzzled, as if everyone you know has enough unicoins to do what you just did on a daily basis.

Comment: +1 for answering the question as written, rather than assuming he meant *unicoins*.

Comment: Um, ew. Who knows where those unicoins have been?

Comment: Awesome answer. I think you win. ;-)

Answer (score 11):

I'm sorry we were unclear. Unicoins are not transferable to reputation.

That being said, send us bacon and we'll negotiate a fair trade.

Comment: ... but what if we're vegetarian?

Comment: @hichris123 then you should have no issues sending us your bacon?

Comment: @NickCraver - Finally I found someone who will take my bacon! RE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/227800/178816 . I have palletized 1400 lbs. of bacon and shipped it ground to Stack Exchange Inc.
110 William St, 28th Floor
New York, NY 10038 and am eagerly awaiting my Unicoin reward.

Comment: The bacon payment option isn't working for me :(  Do you accept PigPal?

Comment: @nzifnab this need not be through *ahem* official channels...

Answer (score 4):

It's on the second page of the powerups.
You can multiply your reputation up to 10x.

FUNNY!!!!

**[EDIT]**

I love these funny things - like UniCoins, the Winter Hats, ...

Comment: The only real answer has a score of 0...
???

Comment: Funny... isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

Unicoin is traded on [MtPLOX](http://newchg.com/unicoin/). (Magic Type Pony Limited Online eXchange). They will happily hold your Unicoins for you indefinitely until they implement an exchange path to SO rep or declare bankruptcy.

Answer (score 2):

I spend 10k dollars on unicoins and it's just a April Fools Day joke?

LOL

And my money?

Comment: That's gone. Forever.

Comment: OMG =[ i should apply this money on other thing, i know my mother is aways right.

Comment: You should always give her the benefit of doubt...

Comment: And my 21321321 clicks to earn unicoins?

Comment: That's your doctor's business... ;)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-DT7bX-B1Mg

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  The game is over...

Comment: I'm going to guess that you live in Asia, Australia, or somewhere around there.

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat I'm a globe-trotter.

Comment: [It's not over until we decide it is](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V8lT1o0sDwI) nsfw

Comment: In Italy we still have 2 hrs+ of fun!! But we started some hours later...

Comment: I want to flag this answer as too localized, but all I see is 'because unicorns'.

Answer (score 1):

You should cut everyone's rep so many times that everyone else loses his moderation privileges. Then you can take over the control of stackoverflow and set your own rules. Be quick - the others might have the same plan.